# Creating hive with multiple parquets

Tags: scala, hive, parquet

I have parquet folders with their name as "yearquarter" starting from (2007q1 - 2020q3). The hive tables I am creating should pull data from only 2014q1 through 2020q2. How do i achieve this?

Comment: Is this a hive question or a scala spark question?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the parquet folder names and add a prefix to them like `yearquarter=2001q1` (for example) which indicates what column stores these values, so it sits in a hierarchy under a top level folder (named `table_name` below).

```
table_name
|
 - yearquarter=2001q1
 - yearquarter=2001q2
  .
  .
 - yearquarter=2020q3
```

Hive-based solution:

You would then create an `external` hive table which is located at the top level folder. You choose `external` so you can set the location. The table schema should correspond to the column labels in the files.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TABLE_NAME (
   col_name1 HIVE_TYPE, 
   ..., 
   col_nameN HIVE_TYPE)
PARTITIONED BY (yearquarter STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/location/to/your/table_name';
```

After you have a hive table on your folder hierarchy, partitioned by the folders, you create a hive view which uses a `WHERE` clause to `SELECT` a subset.

```
CREATE VIEW view_name 
AS SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE yearquarter >= "2014q1" AND yearquarter <= "2020q2";
```

Performing a `SELECT` from this view will then provide the required range.

Spark-based solution:

You create a `DataFrame` which reads the top level location. Because you stored the hierarchy like `yearquarter=2001q1`, these values are automatically read into a column labeled `yearquarter`.

```
// Read parquet hierarchy. The schema (if present) is automatically detected.
val df = spark.read.parquet("/location/to/your/table_name")

// Set filter condition to use.
val filterCondition = col("yearquarter") >= "2014q1" && col("yearquarter") <= "2020q2"

// Filter according to condition.
val filtered = df.filter(filterCondition)
```